# .NET Framework API, runs when manually started, won't run in IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, webapi

I have a Web API that is acting as middleware between a PHP based website and a very legacy .DLL file.

When I start the compiled .exe, the api starts up on http://localhost:5000, and everything works. The website sends the request to the .NET API, which interacts with the .dll file.

However, when I run the .NET Api in IIS, I get this error when I hit the same endpoint:

> Most likely causes:
> The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
> A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.
>
> Things you can try:
> Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI application.
> Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this error.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
> Module     AspNetCoreModule
> Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
> Handler    aspNetCore
> Error Code     0x80072efe

I just tried. My web.config looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">     <system.webServer>
      <environmentVariables>
             <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
         </environmentVariables>
     </system.webServer>
   </location>
 </configuration>
 <!--ProjectGuid: fb3cd58e-e854-43d2-b64e-371bb57c9bb8-->
```

Getting this error:

> Module
> IIS Web Core Notification
> Unknown Handler
> Not yet determined
> Error Code       0x8007000d

I'm not sure what the difference would be? I am not all that experienced with IIS.

Comment: You missed too many details, including but not limited to 1) .NET Framework, or .NET Core? You have to make that clear. 2) What's the IIS configuration when you said "run the .NET Api in IIS"?

Comment: Sorry, .NET Framework (is in the title)

Comment: It is set up as a Website, binded to port 5000, with an AppPool setting of:
.NET CLR 4.0
Integrated pipeline

Comment: Then you should delete anything related to .NET Core in your `web.config` file so that such errors won't appear.

Comment: @LexLi I just tried. my web.config looks like this;
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
   <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: fb3cd58e-e854-43d2-b64e-371bb57c9bb8-->`

Getting this error:
`Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code    0x8007000d`

Comment: Edit your question to include `web.config`, and also paste the complete error page.